# EF6 Entity Data Model Designer not available with target framework .net 5.0

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-5

I have an existing .NET Framework-based solution that I'm migrating to .net 5.0. I'm not migrating data access just now: we'll keep using EF6 model-first. After converting projects to .net 5.0 I've tried opening the .edmx file only to get a message:

> The Entity Data Model Designer is unable to display the file you requested.
> The Entity Framework is not available in the target framework currently specified for the project. You can change the target framework of the project or edit the model in the XML Editor.

The target framework is `net5.0`.

Should this work?

Comment: The EDM Designer is removed from .NET Core. Since code-first is more used in modern projects, now DB diagram is more used to visually see schema.

Comment: https://erikej.github.io/ef/dotnetcore/2020/06/15/ef6-use-edmx-dotnetcore.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as per [EF docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/#ef-designer-support?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4025156):

> There's currently no support for using the EF designer directly on
> .NET Core or .NET Standard projects or on an SDK-style .NET Framework
> project.

Thanks to @ErikEJ for [a detailed walkthrough of a workaround](https://erikej.github.io/ef/dotnetcore/2020/06/15/ef6-use-edmx-dotnetcore.html).

Comment: So you have to mantain the old project in .NET Framework, out of the solution, and the new project in .NET5 in the solution, haven't you?

Comment: Yes, you need two projects, and the cs files from .NET Framework project are all included as links in the .NET Core project. I guess (?) they can be in the same solution though.

Comment: At some point the advice to have a dummy legacy .NET FW project in the solution solely for editing of the edmx context was even in the MS documentation, with steps etc. Now they seem to have replaced that page with an advice to use the "EF Core Power Tools" extension which comes with a half-baked database-first something. The extension has its own problems though so I would really like to revert to the two-project approach, but I don't seem to be able to. As soon as I add the edmx file as a link to the new project, it becomes uneditable in both projects. Any workaround for that?